# How to render JSON Associated data from ActiveRecord Includes

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

How do I render grids in JSON from includes query? The code below only outputs Folders.

```
Folder.includes(:grids)

render json: @folders, :include => :grids, root: false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveModelSerializer...!

class FolderSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :grids
end